# Button onclick to click() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a button that reacts to onclick() at the moment, but I want it to work with jquery.

```
$('#nupp1').click(function() {
    raiseButtonAction(realPlayer, gameState);
});
```

raisebuttonaction is in another .js
This piece of code isn't working.
Am I doing something wrong?
edit1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nupp1').click(function() {
        raiseButtonAction(realPlayer, gameState);
    });
});
```

Comment: show the full code and markup, when you assign the handler?

Comment: Where did you put that piece of code?  It should be in a "ready" handler.

Comment: Where are the variables `realPlayer` and `gameState` coming from?

Comment: Is `raisebuttonaction` script being included before this bind script?

Comment: Where/when is this code being run? Part of `$(document.ready)`?

Comment: You need to remember that you need to put it inside `$(document).ready(function() { /* here */ } );` thats what always breaks jquery for me.

Comment: @rocket - everything else is in vsjoo.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have this:

```
<head>
    <scripts />
</head>
<body>
    <a id="nupp1"></a>
</body>
```

You code will not work. jQuery will not be able to find the element. The element must exists for that function to work. So

```
<a id="nupp1"></a>
<script />
```

Will work because `a` is being rendered before the script.

You can also use [`$(document).ready` or `$()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to execute your function when the DOM nodes load.

Or you can use [`jQuery.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

**jQuery API**

- [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) *Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.*
- [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) *Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.*